# Pandas: Find pattern after specific text and replace the pattern

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample dataframe below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['The IO operation at logical block address 0x0 for Disk1 (PDO name: \\Device00024','fddasfsa'],'col2': [1,2])
```

I like to replace the characters between 'Device' and ')' to 'xxxxxx'. Is it possible to do such replacement in pandas?

I thought I can do the following. The code ran with no issue but the replacement never happen.

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].replace(r'\\Device(.*)', 'xxxxxx,regex=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `str.replace` here:

```py
df["col1"] = df["col1"].str.replace(r'\bDevice\d+', 'Devicexxxxxx')
```

The code sample you gave above won't even compile, but it actually looks on the right track.  You made the same mistake I initially made here.  You need to include `Device` in the replacement, not just `xxxxxx`, as your regex match will *consume* the device string along with the numbers.

Comment: somehow this didn't work. I had updated the full text in case the text is conflicting the code.

Comment: @user3782604 My logic is [working in this demo](https://rextester.com/KVCHX64151).  I can speculate that maybe your actual data is something other than what you think.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the digits immediately to the left of Device. Code below

`df['col1'].str.replace('(?<!Device)\d+','xxxxx')`

Comment: this replace the 0x0 to xxxxxxxxx too.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, if you want to have the same number of `x` as digits:

```
df["col1"] = df["col1"].str.replace(
    r"(?<=Device)(\d+)", lambda g: "x" * len(g.group(1)), regex=True
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                        col1  col2
0  adbsdfklj (\Devicexxxxxx)     1
1                   fddasfsa     2
```